# This error comes to me everytime i use loops with scanner in java

Tags: java

This is the error

```
import java.util.*;

public class CWH_Exercise2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
            // Objects
            Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Code 
            System.out.println("Welcome!");
            System.out.print("Your input: ");
            String userMove = sc1.next();
            if (userMove.equalsIgnoreCase("Yep")) {
                System.out.println("Here it is again!");
            }
            else if (userMove.equalsIgnoreCase("Nope")){
                System.out.println("Why I will print it again?");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Try Again");
            }

            // Closes
            sc1.close();
            sc2.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In each of my code where I use for-loop, do-while loop or while loop, this error comes

Comment: What error? You wrote "This is the error" and then just a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use multiple scanners reading from the same input.

Don't close a scanner if you need to read from the same input again, because this closes the input stream and that cannot be reopened.

```
// Declare 1 scanner outside the loop.
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
// Remove sc2

// Loop to do stuff.
// Don't close sc1 at all: closing sc1 closes System.in;
// you didn't open System.in, so you shouldn't close it either.
for(int i = 0;i<=5;i++){
  // Stuff.
}
```